# How to select the first value by default?

Tags: javascript, react-native, native-base

I have Picker component from native-base. And I want that first value was selected by default automatically

From database "vaccinationSchemas" is coming. And I want that data was selected.

```
let vacineFormData: any = {
  id: generateUUID(),
  medicineId: "",
  animalId: "",
  diseaseId: "",
  taskId: "",
  analysisTubeId: "",
  eventDate: new Date(),
  vaccinationSchemaId: "",
};

vacineFormPropUpdate(prop: string, value: any) {
    const { vacineFormData } = this.state;
    this.setState({
      vacineFormData: {
        ...vacineFormData,
        [prop]: value,
      },
    });
  }

const schemasData = vaccinationSchemas.map(v=>({
      label:v.id,
      value:v.id
    }))
<Picker
      data={schemasData}
      value={vacineFormData.vaccinationSchemaId}
      onValueChange={v => 
      this.vacineFormPropUpdate("vaccinationSchemaId",v)}
      placeholder={t("global_vaccination_schemas")}
 />
```

Comment: Can you post sample data for `vaccinationSchemas` ?

Comment: @SanyamJain oh sorry. This is gist will help to you https://gist.github.com/bekanur98/c13d090758fb9e86f22b7f150837082f

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
handleChangeOption(val) {
  if (val !== 0) {
    this.setState({selectedValue: val});
  }
}


<View style={Styles.row}>
            <Picker
                selectedValue={this.state.selectedValue}
                onValueChange={this.handleChangeOption}
              >
              {schemasData.map(item=>
              <Picker.Item label={item.label} value={item.value} />)
              }
            </Picker>
</View>
```